# Multisite, domain mapping and SSL?

Tags: multisite, ssl

I have been doing alot of research and everything on the subject seems to be one of areas where everyone is finding some sort of different solution. 
I am setting up a network something like edublogs.com and some sites will have mapped domains. I need to have some pages secured for the sites. These pages include some custom admin user profiles pages and checkout pages for a simple shopping cart/store system. 
I am not looking for how to set it up, but if it is possible on a multisite and if anyone here has personaly accoumplished it succsesfully?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, I have setup a multisite install with domain mapping, and SSL on one of the domains.

Comment: I know I was not asking on how to set it up, but how did you configure it and how is the performance on that site. Thanks